# Nginx $is_args and $args cleared after rewrite

Tags: nginx, server, args

I am trying to write in the access log some info that depends on whether the original request had query params or not, and for this purpose I use $is_args within the $http block.

For instance, if the received request was http://www.website.com/something&a=1&b=2, the access log line should be

```
.... [GET params:true] ...
```

But if the requet was http://www.website.com/something, then the access log line should be

```
.... [GET params:false] ...
```

I also have a `location` context which does a rewrite:

```
    if ( $redirect_to_somewhere = "true") {
        return 302 $redirect_loc;
    }
```

My problem is that after the rewrite is executed, `$args` and `$is_args` variables get empty and return nothing.
If the rewrite doesn't happen, $args and $is_args have the correct values from the original request.

What can I do to have the `$is_args` value of the original request despite the rewrite?
My only solution that currently works is to set a variable just before the return:

```
set $original_is_args $is_args;
```

and then use it outside the server scope, but I've seen warnings not to use variables that are set this way outside server{}.
I also prefer not to use regex matching for performance reasons.

Is there a possible solution?

Edit: After the redirection, there's a navigation to an error page(which is normal in my case) so the args from the original request aren't reserved. The question is still valid - how to still have original args(or is_args) without having to parse $request_uri.

Comment: Does `$redirect_loc` include the query string? Perhaps you should use: `return 302 $redirect_loc$is_args$args;`

Comment: @RichardSmith Even more than that, it includes $request_uri which contains the original path & args but still, `$is_args` and `$args` are both empty.

Comment: Sorry, actually after the redirection there's a nav to error page which is normal in my case.. so the args aren't expected to be passed.